# Access a value in a 2D array through programming in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, 2d

I create Aliment struct.
And i have an array of Aliment.

```
struct Aliment {
    let name: String
    let vitamineARetinol: Float
    let vitaminC: Float
    let vitaminD: Float
    let calories: Float
    let grammage: Float
}

let ListAlimentsBrut = [
    Aliment(name: "Orange", vitamineARetinol: 0.5, vitaminC: 57, vitaminD: 0.98, calories: 140, grammage: 100),
    Aliment(name: "Pomme", vitamineARetinol: 0.2, vitaminC: 6.25, vitaminD: 0.38, calories: 120, grammage: 100),
    Aliment(name: "Poire", vitamineARetinol: 0.1, vitaminC: 4.62, vitaminD: 0.58, calories: 140, grammage: 100),
    Aliment(name: "Laitue", vitamineARetinol: 0.3, vitaminC: 4.72, vitaminD: 0.92, calories: 105, grammage: 100),
    Aliment(name: "Laitue", vitamineARetinol: 0.7, vitaminC: 4.72, vitaminD: 0.63, calories: 122, grammage: 100),
    Aliment(name: "Poivron Jaune", vitamineARetinol: 0, vitaminC: 184, vitaminD: 0, calories: 29.2, grammage: 100)
]
```

how can i access the calorie value of the second food, i mean 120 calories for "Pomme", but through programming and not directly.
Thank you.

Comment: You want to access to the second element ? Or the element where "Pomme" is the the `name` of the `Aliment`?

Comment: The second element

Comment: `ListAlimentsBrut[1].calories`

Comment: ListAlimentsBrut[1].calories didn't work.

Comment: With more explicit: `let secondAlimentWhichIsPomme = ListAlimentsBrut[1]`, `let calories = secondAlimentWhichIsPomme.calories`. Unrelated, but I'd recommend to name your var starting with a lowercase: `ListAlimentsBrut`=> `listAlimentsBrut

Comment: @Wahib Indices/Index starts at zero in programming (usually).

Comment: yes of course @Larme, but it didn't work

Comment: What didn't work? Where? What did you write exactly? Which line (since I separated the lines)? Did you get an error? Unexpected result? Crash? Error message? Do we have to guess what should be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Do you have an error?

Comment: it said: error: aaa.playground:65:33: error: use of unresolved identifier 'ListAlimentsResorbSpecificDeficit'
let secondAlimentWhichIsPomme = ListAlimentsResorbSpecificDeficit[1]
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Where is defined `ListAlimentsResorbSpecificDeficit`? In the code you gave, it's `ListAlimentsBrut` not `ListAlimentsResorbSpecificDeficit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the second element of the an array using the subscript method (`arrayProperty[index]`), note that the first element has an index of 0, in your case :

```
ListAlimentsBrut[1].calories
```

Also, I would recommend to follow the naming convention in swift meaning that the property ListAlimentsBrut should start with a lower case and to name the property without saying the type of the data (here list)and keeping consistency between language (just english, not a mix of french and english) like that for exemple :

```
let rawIngredients = [...]
```